# How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

The situation is somewhat like:

```js
const searchKeyPressHandler = (appDispatch: any, e: any) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        appDispatch({ type: "closeSearch" })
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", searchKeyPressHandler); // <-- error on searchKeyPressHandler
return () => document.removeEventListener("keyup", searchKeyPressHandler); // <-- error on searchKeyPressHandler
```

`searchKeyPressHandler` return error using typescript and I don't know how I can avoid it.

`document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { searchKeyPressHandler(appDispatch, e) });`
could be a solution for `addEventListener`

but it is not useful for `removeEventListener` because the event will be never removed with
`return () => document.removeEventListener("keyup", function (e) { searchKeyPressHandler(appDispatch, e) });`.

[image: error]

Comment: Dont forget to pass arguments

Comment: How about the error message ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just wrap the actual event handler in an anonymous function and that function can then call your function with its arguments. But don't forget that event handlers are automatically passed a reference to the event that triggered them, so capture that in the outer handler and pass it along with your other arguments:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){ searchKeyPressHandler(event, x,y,z); });
```

Or, if you need to utilize the function that you are setting up as the "wrapper" more than once (in the case of having to remove the listener later), you'd just declare the function with a name and pass that name into `.addEventListner()` as follows:

```
function handler(event){ 
  searchKeyPressHandler(event, x,y,z); 
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", handler);

// And later...
document.removeEventListener("keyup", handler);
```

Comment: Also shorter to use an arrow function `document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => searchKeyPressHandler(event, x,y,z));
`

Comment: @johannchopin Yes, but shorter !== better. And since you don't get `this` bound to the element that triggered the function with arrow functions, I prefer not to use them for event binding.

Comment: this soluton is ok for `addEventListener` but it is not ok with `removeEventListener` (otherwise the event will be never removed)

Comment: @FrancescoOrsi In that case, simply don't pass an anonymous function, rather declare the function and then just pass that name. I'll update the answer to show both approaches.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are simply the best!!! that one was the solution I was looking for!! Thank You!!!! Super Thank You :)